# Sum all columns in LINQ query using a custom class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'm new to using LINQ in VB.Net (within ASP.Net) and I can't seem to figure out how to Sum the data returned in the following query. In my actual code there are 26 items instead of just three and I use a custom class to organize them. I've found countless examples of how to sum a few individual items when selecting them individually but nothing on summing 26 separate columns organized in a class.

Edit: Sorry for not being as clear earlier. I am hoping to sum each column. For example if I select 7 days of data rather than 7 rows with item1, item2, and item3 it would just be one row with three columns all being the totals of those rows. Hope that makes sense...

```
Public Class cQuery
    Public Property Item1 As Integer
    Public Property Item2 As Integer
    Public Property Item3 As Integer
End Class

Dim Query = From data In db.CombinedData
                Select New cQuery With {
                                        .Item1 = data.item01,
                                        .Item2 = data.item02,
                                        .Item3 = data.item03
                                       }
```

UPDATE:
So I ended up taking the advice and just using a datatable. I agree, it's a lot easier to work with. Here's what I ended up doing to sum all of the columns. This will take any datatable as an input and spit out a new datatable with an identical structure just with one row containing the summed values of the numeric columns.

```
Public Function SumTableRows(dtInTable As DataTable) As DataTable
        Dim dtOutTable As New DataTable
        dtOutTable = dtInTable.Clone()
        dtOutTable.Rows.Add()
        For i As Integer = 0 To dtOutTable.Columns.Count - 1
        If IsNumeric(dtInTable.Rows(0).Item(i)) Then
            dtOutTable.Rows(0).Item(i) = dtInTable.Compute("Sum(" + dtInTable.Columns(i).ColumnName + ")", "")
        End If
    Next
    Return dtOutTable
End Function
```

Comment: It is not clear if you want the sum for every single row (the sum of the 26 fields of a row, the the sum of the next fields' row and so on till the end) or if your want the sum of all fields and all rows as a unique grand total. Could you explain better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be loading the data from a database, a better option would probably be to store the data as a DataTable, rather than a collection of custom class objects. This gives you more options to access the data by row or column.